# Windows Universal App On WDKRemoteUser in Windows 10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, driver, win-universal-app

When I deploy driver on my windows 10 target PC its switches to WDKRemoteUser account by it self. The driver is deployed successfully.

I have problem with windows universal application, my purpose is to check the application with **read** and **write** *ioctl* of the deployed driver. But the WDKRemoteUser is not letting me to deploy the windows application via visual studio on my **HOST** machine as its asking for authentication and i dont have WDKRemoteUser password !!!

My Host Enviorment :-
Windows 10 (Build 10130) X64 and Visual Studio 2015 RC edition...

My Target Enviorment :-
Windows 10 (Build 10130) X64 and Visual Studio 2015 Remote Tools installed...

Comment: Log in to the target computer with an admin account. Go to 'Edit Local Users and Groups'.  You should see the 'WDKRemoteUser' in the list. Right-click the user and 'Set Password...'. Put in a password that will work  with your group password policy. Sign out and login as ".\WDKRemoteUser" with your current password. Retry the provisioning with the corresponding debug settings.

Comment: The above thing worked for me... Remember you should have remote tools for visual studio installed on the target PC....

Comment: I referred :- http://hackmridul.blogspot.in/2014/11/wdkremoteuser-woes.html